# Cannot properly lay out rows using CSS Grid Layout

Tags: css, layout, grid

I'm attempting to use CSS Grid Layout as [described here](http://www.creativebloq.com/css3/introducing-css-grid-layout-spec-111517952).

My problem is that after having successfully coded two rows of the grid layout, I cannot get the layout for the third row right. The third row somehow covers up the second row.

Below is the basic structure of the code to give an idea of what I'm trying to do. My repository with all the code is [here](https://github.com/orlando21/product-showcase).

When looking at the published page, it's apparent that the first two rows are correctly laid out, but unfortunately the third row won't adhere to the grid layout (and is overlaid on the second row).

Would anyone know how I can properly lay out the third row?

Structure of my HTML:

```
    <body>

    <header class="hero">
    </header>

    <main role="main">

    <section class="tech">
    </section>

    <section class="afford">
        <h1>This heading should be in the next section</h1>
    </section>

    </main>

    </body>
```

Structure of CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: grid;
    margin: 0 auto;
    grid-template-columns: 10% auto auto 10%;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto auto auto auto;
    grid-template-areas: "hero          hero          hero         hero"
                         "tech          tech          tech         tech"
                         "afford        afford        afford       afford"
                         ". .   .   ."
                         ". .   .   .";
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100vh;
}

.hero {
    grid-area: hero;
    background-image: url('../images/people-working.jpg');
    width: 100%;
    height: 928px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.tech {
    grid-area: tech;
    width: 100%;
    height: 712px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
}

.afford {
    grid-area: afford;
    width: 100%;
    height: 832px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the position: absolute; the markup will then be stacked. I removed most of the code in this example but I think it is what you are going for at a basic structure level:

http://codepen.io/stacy/pen/157042a40a8b4c23f1bad5c12719c8f5?editors=1100

```
body {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    // grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    // grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-template-areas: "hero"
                         "tech"
                         "afford";
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
 }

.hero {
    grid-area: hero;
}

.tech {
    grid-area: tech;
}

.afford {
    grid-area: afford;
}
```

You won't need the width's if you declare either the number of columns each template area would fill or if you declare the grid-template-columns widths.

Keep in mind, if you add grid to the body, it won't apply to elements within each grid area. One day hopefully we will see the subgrid spec come to life, but until then, we will have to apply it the same as we do flexbox. I noticed you declared 4 columns and spanned each grid area 4 times so far which is why I am bringing this up.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize the role that `position:absolute` played in this so I removed it and now it works.